# How to convert an ISO time format to something like dd/mm/yy, hh:mm:ss AM/PM?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, string-formatting, datetime-format

let currdate =2022-11-28T10:26:00.949Z

```
I have to convert the date like 
28 Nov , 2022 :4:05:33 PM
```

Please suggest , tried some examples but not getting like this

Thanks

Comment: These types of conversions are ruthless a few times, I always try to use Timestamps like in here https://www.epochconverter.com/ that are universally accepted and easy to convert.

Comment: @Malik could you please help me with some piece of code

Comment: The OP might have a look into the [`DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) formatter options of the [ECMAScript Internationalization API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl)

Comment: SO is here to help you with code you've written, not to write it for you. Post what you've tried, others will provide answers to achieve the result you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP might have a look into the [`DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) formatter options of the [ECMAScript Internationalization API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl).

```js
const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {
  year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit',
  hour: 'numeric', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit',
  hourCycle: 'h12',
});

console.log(
  formatter
    .format(
      new Date('2022-11-28T10:26:00.949Z')
    )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -2):

use moment.js for this

```
moment("2022-11-28T10:26:00.949Z").format("DD MMM , yyyy :h:mm:ss A")
```

Comment: Thanks , do we have anything withoutght moment ?

Comment: you can use  luxon.js instead of moment